# What does つく mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I hope this question is not too dumb.
The context comes from Spirited Away:

> *Mother father and daughter arrive at some empty food stand*

> (Fater) すみませーん、どなたかいませんかー？

> (Mother) 千尋{ちひろ}もおいで、おいしそうよ。

> (Father) すいませーん！

> (Mother) いいわよ、そのうち来たらお金払えばいいんだから。

> (Father) そうだな。そっちにいいやつが… *(looking at food)*

> ...

> (Chihiro) ねぇ帰ろ、お店の人に怒られるよ。

> (Father) 大丈夫、お父さんがついてるんだから。カードも財布も持ってるし。

> ...

I can't really grasp the sense of that ついてる at the end of the dialogue.
Initially I simply thought it referred to the card and wallet cited in the second sentence, but I don't really think this works since there's that し.
On jisho.org I found these possible meanings:

1. to be settled; to be resolved
2. to side with (I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with this one but you never know)

Could number 1 actually be the answer? I feel like it may be, but I can't really grasp the usage and I'm finding it difficult searching example sentences for this exact meaning of the verb.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just [sense 3 of 付く](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F_%28%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%29/) — i.e. "to be together with". So the last two lines of dialogue might be translated as follows:

> (Chihiro) ねぇ帰ろ、お店の人に怒られるよ。
> Hey dad, let's go... the people in the shop are gonna get angry at us. 
> (Father) 大丈夫、お父さんがついてるんだから。カードも財布も持ってるし。
> Don't worry, dad will be right here with you. I've got my credit card and my wallet anyway.

Comment: For OP:  With this definition come the verbs ついていく and ついてくる meaning "to go/come (accompanying) along with".

Comment: Now that I think about I think I had that meaning in my mind somewhere from previous experience but too bad it didn't come to surface at the right time. Thank you!

Comment: May I also ask you how do you get a newline without formatting a whole new comment, like I did? If I just hit newline in the same comment the preview would just show the new line concatenated on the same line.

Comment: @GianniTrattore that isn't supported by the Stack Exchange software as far as I know, and I don't see a comment with an added newline here, either.

Comment: @GianniTrattore from the [formatting help](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), you can end the line with 2 spaces to allow linebreak on the post :)

Comment: @giannitrattore — Poster here! You can also do it by ending the line with a backslash: \